# Devise how to redirect to different page (based on some parameter) after sign out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

In my application, I have two different login forms from two controller which will both sign_in through the Devise::SessionsController
After signing in, the problem I face is that when I sign out, I want to redirect the path back to the original login forms from which the user logged in depending on the user type.

```
Ex: user.type = doctor --> goes to login page1 (on logout)

 user.type = patient --> goes to login page2 (on logout)
```

I tried using the `after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)` to redirect:

```
if user.type = doctor

login_path1

else user.type = patient

login_path2

end
```

But I realise at this point, all params have been deleted. Is there anyway to not delete certain params reaching here ? or how to go about this situation

This is my first time asking a question here. So bear with me, if im doing this wrong

Comment: May I ask what is your Devise routes configuration looks like currently?

Comment: And the Devise version?

Answer (score 0):

Try

> redirect_to request.parameters.merge controller: "your_controller", action: "your_action"